# this.$route becomes undefined in one component if I add beforeRouteEnter in another

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm stuck. For some reason I can't access this.$route anymore in one component after I put beforeRouteEnter method in another component.

My app looks like this.

```
<div id="app">
    <settings-modal></settings-modal>

    <router-view name="CalendarMonthView"></router-view>
</div>
```

The CalendarMonthView component is loaded in the router view. And there is a beforeRouteEnter inside it. But then my SettingsModal component says that on created() the this.$params is undefined. Before I used beforeRouteEnter it wasn't undefined.

**CalendarMonthView component**

```
export default {
    ...

    // to.params.selectedYear  = 2019
    // to.params.selectedMonth = 3

    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next)
    {
        Month.getDays({
            year: to.params.selectedYear,
            month: to.params.selectedMonth,
         }).then(response => {
             store.monthDays = response.data
             next()
         })
    }
}
```

**SettingsModal component**

```
export default {
    ...

    created()
    {
        // undefined
        console.log('selectedYear: ', this.$route.params.selectedYear)

        // undefined
        console.log('selectedMonth: ', this.$route.params.selectedMonth)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe related, the `beforeRouteEnter` function does not have access to `this`. I don't see you referencing `this` in `beforeRouteEnter`, but the described bug fits a pattern. Read the docs, they may help: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by this function `Month.getDays()` . Maybe there was an error in the function that caused `next()` not to be called.You should check that your function is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Route params aren't available yet as the navigation hasn't finished. It needs to wait for `Month.getDays` promise to resolve.

You try to access the params from `SettingsModal` as soon as it is created which happens before the promise resolves.

You can try to `watch` `$route` and check the params then.

```
watch: {
  '$route': 'checkParams'
 },
```

This goes in `SettingsModal`.